# Is there an easy way to convert existing Jenkins freestyle job to New Jenkins 2.x pipeline view

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have tons of existing Freestyle Jenkins jobs in my old Jenkins Instance and now I would like to migrate them to New Jenkins 2.0 pipeline jobs using a Jenkins file.

I am following this page to create a Jenkins file: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/

Can someone please suggest me if there is any easy way (or) plugin i can use to convert these existing job's to pipeline view.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried the plugin but while searching for same i came across this post:
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/12/15/auto-convert-freestyle-jenkins-jobs-to-coded-pipeline/

Maybe this can help. Will update more after actually giving it a ago. You can go through and try by yourself as well.

Answer (score 2):

don't think there is an automatic tool to convert jobs.

We created all new jobs with [Jenkins DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

for the Jenkinsfile - we created some good examples of our basic flows and each team convert the relevant jobs.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this tool from cloudbees: [declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant](https://plugins.jenkins.io/declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant/)